PINETAB2 – 10.1″ 8GB/128GB ARM based Linux tablet with detachable backlit keyboard
It is possible installation on that device Linux Ubuntu Desktop Gnome?
That is easy or not.
What can be wrong?
CHASSIS:
Dimensions: 242mm x 161mm x 9mm
Weight: 520 grams (without keyboard), 990 grams (includes keyboard)
Build: Metal and Plastic
Color: Silver Gray

DISPLAY:
Type: HD IPS capacitive touchscreen, 16.7M colors
Size: 10.1 inches
Resolution: 1280×800 pixels, 16:10 ratio

PLATFORM:
OS: DanctNix Arch Linux
Chipset: Rockchip RK3566
CPU: 64-bit Quad-core 1.8 GHz ARM Cortex A-55
GPU: MALI-G52

MEMORY:
Internal Flash Memory: 128GB eMMC module
System Memory: 8GB LPDDR4 SDRAM
Expansion: micro SD Card support SDHC and SDXC, up to 2TB

CAMERA:
Main Camera: Single 5MP, LED Flash
Selfie Camera: Single 2MP

SOUND:
Loudspeaker: Yes, stereo
3.5mm jack with mic: Yes, stereo

COMMUNICATION:
WLAN: Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n, dual-band, hotspot
Bluetooth: 5.0, A2DP

FEATURES:
USB port: 1x USB 3.0 port (front side 3.0, rear side 2.0), 1x USB Type-C 2.0 port (also use as charging and debug port)
USB 2.0 docking port
HD Video out

BATTERY:
Li-Po 6000mAh battery
Charging: 15W – 5V 3A

PACKAGE:
PineTab version2
Detached backlit keyboard, also act as cover and stand
USB-A to USB-C charging cable

Thanks for answers.

Sorry but hardware shopping is off topic on this site. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Or no one have.
